# virtualenvwrapper preactivate error on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm on Windows 10. I have virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed and this error happens:
When I create a new environment appears this error:

```
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\TestEnv\bin\preactivate": [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I tried to install MYSYS and I reinstalled virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper but nothing worked. Can anybody help?